# Recording Audio Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I've tried recording audio using AudioVideoCaptureDevice class:

```
        //Recording
        var fileUri = new Uri(file.Path);
        var targetStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

        var mAudioCaptureDevice = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenForAudioOnlyAsync();
        mAudioCaptureDevice.AudioEncodingFormat = CameraCaptureAudioFormat.Aac;
        await mAudioCaptureDevice.StartRecordingToStreamAsync(targetStream);
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        await mAudioCaptureDevice.StopRecordingAsync();
        mAudioCaptureDevice.Dispose();
        mAudioCaptureDevice = null;

        await targetStream.FlushAsync();
        targetStream.Dispose();
        targetStream = null;

        //Playing
        SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(new FileStream(file.Path, System.IO.FileMode.Open));
        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
        effect.Play();
```

and it keeps raising an error on the playing section:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the wrong format. As [SoundEffect.FromStream documentation says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.fromstream.aspx):

> The Stream object must point to the head of a valid PCM wave file. Also, this wave file must be in the RIFF bitstream format.
>
> The audio format has the following restrictions: 
> •Must be a PCM wave file
> •Can only be mono or stereo
> •Must be 8 or 16 bit
> •Sample rate must be between 8,000 Hz and 48,000 Hz

Have you tired with a `.wav` file instead of `.aac`?